# A0 (landscape) sheet inside A4 paper

Tags: margins, koma-script, paper-size

Well I "can" do this using the koma options.. However it results in a warning and the effect isn't completelly what I like it to be.

First the way I do it is:

```
\clearpage
\KOMAoptions{paper=A3,paper=portrait}
\recalctypearea

\chapter{Chosen airfoil and wing shape}
\label{app:cad-airfoil}



\clearpage
\KOMAoptions{paper=A4,paper=portrait}
\recalctypearea
```

Now this results in a warning as follow:

> /appendixAirfoil.tex: Package typearea Warning: Bad type area
>   settings! (typearea) The detected line width is about 55% (typearea)
>   larger than the heuristically detected line width. (typearea) You
>   should e.g. decrease DIV, increase fontsize (typearea) or change
>   papersize.

Another problem I have with above is that the margins are still relative to the paper size. Making the margins ridiculously large, and the actually area where I can put the cad drawing very small. (Ok I could put the cad at an offset from the margin, however then the accompanying text looks weird staring at a random position).

So How can I fix this problem with the margins (or problems, though I think it is the same one?). - Preferably just keep the same margins as A4 sheets, and if that's not easily possible manually set them?

Comment: Could you explain what you want to do? Squeezing a A0 paper into the space used for A4?

Comment: No just having an A0 paper as page "80"  in a report.

Comment: You know, that A0 is 'slightly' larger than A4? ;-)

Comment: Just a lil' bit yes :P. - But I'll have to include the detailed CAD drawings anyways, many times i can fit it on A3 or A2, but sometimes i need A0 - but question remains the same.

Comment: Are we talking of a screen document or a printed document?

Comment: Well I "may deliver it as an emailed PDF" - but it "should be able to be printed", however that the printing works is completelly up to the tutor (they typically remove the CADs for printing during testing of how well it looks in grayscale). - But I don't see how this is related to the problem really?

Answer (score 1):

Changing the papersize mid document is a strange thing for me. I
would try to put stuff like that in the appendix.

Internally, package `typearea` takes care of laying out the text
block on the page. With the code below you get an A0-page mid
document, the high `DIV` value decreases the amrgin size and
increases width and height of the text block.

But why does package `typearea` give a warning? Typearea tries to
lay a certain amount of glyphs on the line to result in the best
readability (which is said to be around 66 to 70 glyphs for a
casual reader). As far as text is concerned, imagine holding an
A0 page in your hand with a font size of just 11 pt. You would
have to turn your head a lot. Hence the warning, »Hey, this is
bad, think about it.«

Maybe it would be easier to include the pdf using `\includepdf`
from package `pdfpages`?

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\storeareas\normalpage
\cleardoubleoddpage
\KOMAoptions{paper=a0,paper=landscape,pagesize,DIV=50,}
\blindtext
\cleardoubleoddpage
\KOMAoptions{paper=a4,paper=portrait,pagesize}
\normalpage
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: Of course it is in the appendix - but that is still part of the document right? And we still wish to be be able to refer to specific parts of that appendix/have page numbering inside the appendix (and same style headings....).

Comment: @paul23 Does that mean you want to have headings of 11 pt (default) on a A0 page? By appendix, i mean some special pages you can take out of the book/report, i.e. completely different print but referencable.